# Spring PagingAndSorting repository returning incosistent values

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, paging, jparepository

I have a problem with consistency, specifically with returning values when calling a page repository method.
I have a controller method, that has parameters: Long conferenceId, String query, Pageable pageable.

```
@GetMapping("/api/conferences/{conferenceId}/submissions")
public Page<SubmissionDetailDto> getPagedSubmissionsByConferenceId(
    @PathVariable("conferenceId") Long conferenceId,
    @RequestParam(required = false) Optional<String> query,
    Pageable pageable
) {
    System.out.println("Get paged submissions by conferenceId, by query, was called, " + conferenceId + ", " + query);
    return submissionService.getPagedSubmissionsByConferenceIdSearchBySurname(conferenceId, query, pageable);
}
```

From the controller I call a service method to return results based on these parameters.

```
public Page<SubmissionDetailDto> getPagedSubmissionsByConferenceIdSearchBySurname(Long conferenceId, Optional<String> query, Pageable pageable) {
    String searchQuery = query.isPresent() ? query.get() : "";
    return (Strings.isBlank(searchQuery)) ?
        mapToPagedSubmissionDetail(submissionPageRepository.searchByConferenceIdOrderByOrderNumber(conferenceId, pageable)) :
        mapToPagedSubmissionDetail(submissionPageRepository.findByConferenceIdAndContactsSurnameStartsWithIgnoreCase(conferenceId, searchQuery, pageable));
}
```

The service method calls a **PagingAndSortingRepository** method to return some values based on these parameters (id, query, Pageable) *or* only a **searchByConferenceIdOrderByOrderNumber** method.

```
@Repository
public interface SubmissionPageRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<SubmissionEntity, UUID> {
    Page<SubmissionEntity> searchByConferenceIdOrderByOrderNumber(Long conferenceId, Pageable pageable);
    Page<SubmissionEntity> findByConferenceIdAndContactsSurnameStartsWithIgnoreCase(Long conferenceId, String query, Pageable pageable);
}
```

The error is not quite obvious, but when I tried to search (by query): "B", the final number of elements comes to number, smaller than if i search by "Be", how could this be possible?
The error disappears, when I increase the size of the pageSize from 10 (default by frontend) to 100, then the final number of elements is right.

I tried to call the method from Postman with
`page: 0, size: 10, sort: orderNumber,ASC and query: "B"`
And the numberOfElements was smaller, if i changed the query to "Be"

I tried to increase the pageSize from 10 to 100 and it worked, but i would like to have 10 results per page and not 100.

I think, that it could be because of the way the PagingAndSortingRepository handles the entities.

Postman pictures:

[Postman GET request with query B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d12XE.png)

[Postman GET request with query Be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssP9k.png)

**Cause:**

When lurking around the database, i deleted some of the contacts, so that a 1 submission has only 1 contact, and the result set is now correct. The implementation of the repository could be looking only at the number of submissions with join table, that equals to the pageSize, pageSize: 10 -> repository looks only at first 10 rows in a join table between submission and contacts.

Now, how could this be fixed?

**FIX**

I had to add `GROUP BY` clause to the SQL code, that was being sent to the database, because the generated SQL code, by JPA, was not working properly with this setup.

Comment: It should both be `findBy...` not `searchBy`. If there are multiple records a cartesian product will occur and the results can be different, especially if you don't have a proper equals/hashcode/toString method in your entity (or none of those). Next to that your methods are weird as you have an order in your method name but also pass a pagable.

Comment: By [Spring JPA documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repository-query-keywords), both search..by and find..by could be used in the methods. After changing both of the repository methods to findBy.. the issue still persists. I added a Lombok @EqualsAndHashCode annotation to the Contact and SubmissionEntity, but the issue also persists. Also the error is with the `findByConferenceIdAndContactsSurnameStartsWithIgnoreCase` method, because if the query is empty == "", the order method does not get called. Could you elaborate on the cartesian product?

Comment: DOn't use lombok `@data` and friends for JPA they generate terrible and wrong implementations. See https://deinum.biz/2019-02-13-Lombok-Data-Ojects-Arent-Entities/, so implement correct methods.

Comment: I tried using only the `@Getter` and `@Setter` annotation, but it did not work.
I also tried the `BaseEntity` from the blog post link, but it did not work either.
At last I tried implementing only the `hashCode` and `equals` methods, but it also did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a `GROUP BY` to an existing clause, as a custom query, that was being sent to the database, that fixed this problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).